# Grub customizer error

Tags: grub2

When I try to update grub by using grub-customizer it gives me error

[image]

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: lucky you, i get "error building  boot sequence" and can't even "ok" the entry editor despite the fact that everything has a green check and is correct!

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, there is an error in line 299 of the generated GRUB config file. Check for errors in the `/etc/default/grub`, `/etc/grub.d/*` files related to generated line 299 (of `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`). Read the error message!